# Change of variable (or measure)?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Hi Everyone: I am reading a book and there is a kind of "change of variable" they make that I do not understand fully. This is what they do: let $B(x,r)$ be a ball of $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ $(N>1)$, $\mu$ a Borel measure in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$, and $f$ a real-valued measurable function on $B(x,r)$. They set $m_{x}(t)=\mu(B(x,t))$, then the integral $\int_{B(x,t)}f(y)d\mu(y)$ becomes $\int^{r}_{0}f(t)dm_{x}(t).$ How come? Any reference? Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is something missing here. Was it stated somewhere that $f$ is spherically symmetric? On the face of it this doesn't make sense, since $t\in[0,r]$ is presumably a real number, while $f:B(x,r)\to\Bbb R$, so $f(t)$ is undefined.

Comment: If the answer I provided was helpful to you, you should upvote and/or accept the answer via the up/down arrows and the checkmark next to the answer. (I assume you are not thanking me for asking for clarification about the problem statement, since that would be strange.)

Comment: You answer is very helpful, but I didn't get what you mean by "upvote and or accept the answer...". Can you be please more explicate?

Comment: Just below and to the left of where this text that I'm typing is, there is the text "1 answer", and below that is a big number zero with double arrows above and below it, and below those, a gray checkmark. The arrows are for everyone to vote on the answers they like or dislike, and the checkmark is just for you, to indicate that an answer satisfied your goal in asking the question.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I got it, and I did it. OK?

Comment: Yes that's right, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to need to make some redefinitions to make sense of your statement.

> Suppose $f:B(x,r)\to\Bbb [0,\infty)$ such that $f(y)=g(|x-y|)$, where $g:[0,r)\to\Bbb [0,\infty)$. (I'll deal only with the nonnegative case for convenience; I'll let you handle the general case on $\Bbb R$.) Define the measure $m_x$ such that $m_x([0,t))=\mu(B(x,t))$. Then:
>   $$\int_{B(x,r)}f\,d\mu=\int_{[0,r)}g\,dm_x.$$

This just the measure theory version of the "method of shells" from intro calc. Define the function $d(y)=|x-y|$, so that $f=g\circ d$, $\boldsymbol{d}^{-1}[[0,t)]=B(x,t)$, and $m_x=\mu\circ \boldsymbol{d}^{-1}$ (note that this is the "lifted" function $\boldsymbol{d}^{-1}:{\scr P}[0,r)\to{\scr P}B(x,r)$ that takes a set to its preimage, not the literal inverse function to $d$, which is not invertible in any case). We have:

\begin{align}
\int_{B(x,r)}f\,d\mu&=\int_0^\infty \mu(\{y|f(y)>z\})\,dz\\
&=\int_0^\infty \mu(\boldsymbol{f}^{-1}[(z,\infty)])\,dz\\
&=\int_0^\infty \mu\circ \boldsymbol{d}^{-1}\circ \boldsymbol{g}^{-1}[(z,\infty)]\,dz\\
&=\int_0^\infty m_x(\boldsymbol{g}^{-1}[(z,\infty)])\,dz\\
&=\int_0^\infty m_x(\{t|g(t)>z\})\,dz\\
&=\int_{[0,r]}g\,dm_x.
\end{align}